# How to delete unused graphic files from iPhone XCode project?

Tags: iphone, xcode

In our iPhone project, it tends to add up a pile of unused image files. I would like to find a neat way to delete theese files from my xcode project. Referances to the images is found in both source and nib-files Do anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: I don't know of one, but this sounds like a great feature for Xcode. You should definitely file a radar asking for Apple to add this feature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113243/how-to-find-unused-images-in-an-xcode-project

Answer (score 1):

Command-shift-f will show a search by project.  With this panel you can find all references to the image in the project.  Once you delete these references Interface Builder will highlight the broken references for you so you can easily delete those.

Comment: I do not understand your suggestion. Can you explaine once more?

Comment: I edited my response, but if it still doesn't make sense please explain which part doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use http://jeffhodnett.github.io/Unused/ to find the unused images.
2. Delete the unused images
3. Delete the references from the implementation files (.m) using project search.
4. Remove the broken references from the xib