# How to find unused images in an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, assets

Has anyone a one-line to find unused images in an Xcode project? (Assuming all the files are referenced by name in code or the project files - no code generated file names.)

These files tend to build up over the life of a project and it can be hard to tell if it's safe to delete any given png.

Comment: Does this work for XCode4 as well? Cmd-Opt-A in XCode4 seems to open "Add files" dialog.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For files which are not included in project, but just hang-around in the folder, you can press

<kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

and they won't be grayed out.

For files which are not referenced neither in xib nor in code, something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROJ=`find . -name '*.xib' -o -name '*.[mh]'`

find . -iname '*.png' | while read png
do
    name=`basename $png`
    if ! grep -qhs "$name" "$PROJ"; then
        echo "$png is not referenced"
    fi
done
```

Comment: If you encounter error: No such file or directory, it is probably due to the spaces in the file path. The quotes needs to be added in grep line, so it goes: if ! grep -qhs  "$name" "$PROJ";

Comment: One scenario where this wouldn't work out is when we might load images programmatically after constructing their names. Like arm1.png, arm2.png.... arm22.png. I might construct their names in the for loop and load. E.g. Games

Comment: If you have images for retina display named with @2x they will list as unused. You can get rid of that by adding an extra if-statement: if [[ "$name" != *@2x* ]]; then

Comment: Cmd+Opt+a seems no longer to work on XCode 5. What does should it trigger?

Comment: cmd+opt+a doesn't seem to gray out files in Images.xcassets even though they are a part of the project :(

Comment: @RajavanyaSubramaniyan, That's why I recently started adding a comment next to the loading code line with all the file names or the first one if there are too many.

Comment: Not working I run script in my project folder and when I checked one of listed image that is marked as not referenced in project using search then I found that image is used in code `fifthPage.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"enjoy.png"];`

Comment: If your project utilizes asset catalog, then instead of finding images with *.png, you could use *.imageset and you won't have to prune "@2x", "@3x" etc as the basename of *.imageset would be enough to look for in the storyboard, xib, swift, .m files.

Answer (score 80):

This is a more robust solution - it checks for *any* reference to the basename in any text file. Note the solutions above that didn't include storyboard files (completely understandable, they didn't exist at the time).

Ack makes this pretty fast, but there are some obvious optimizations to make if this script runs frequently. This code checks every basename twice if you have both retina/non-retina assets, for example.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `find . -name "*.png" -o -name "*.jpg"`; do 
    file=`basename -s .jpg "$i" | xargs basename -s .png | xargs basename -s @2x`
    result=`ack -i "$file"`
    if [ -z "$result" ]; then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done

# Ex: to remove from git
# for i in `./script/unused_images.sh`; do git rm "$i"; done
```

Comment: Install [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) and then do a `brew install ack`.

Comment: Thanks. This answer also handles files and folders with spaces in correctly.

Comment: Excuse my incompetence but how would I execute this on my project folder?

I tried both "sh FindUnusedImages.sh /Development/ProjectFolder" and "bash FindUnusedImages.sh /Development/ProjectFolder".

Comment: @Johnny you need to make the file executable (`chmod a+x FindUnusedImages.sh`), then run it like any other program from bash `./FindUnusedImages.sh`

Comment: I've made a modification to ignore pbxproj files (thus ignoring files that are in the xcode project, but not used in code or nibs/storyboards):

`result=\`ack --ignore-file=match:/.\.pbxproj/ -i "$file"\``

This requires ack 2.0 and up

Comment: @msprague Thank you!  That worked like a charm.  I knew it was something silly I was missing.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @msprague how about `--type=objc` instead of `--ignore blah blah`

Comment: That doesn't search xibs or storyboards for references.  So if there's a resource that's being used in a xib, but not in the code, it won't show up.

Comment: where should I put this script so It can search in my current project? I put that file in my current project but it seems that It's  searching in complete drive.

Comment: milanpanchal, you can put the script anywhere, and you just execute it from whatever directory you want to use as the root for searching for images (e.g. your project root folder). You can put it in ~/script/ for example and then go to your project root folder and run it by pointing to the script directly: ~/script/unused_images.sh

Comment: Does `ack` support `.xib`, `.storyboard`, and `.swift` ?

Comment: Getting error : Error: Failed to download resource "ack"
Download failed: https://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.18-single-file. Their SSL certificate has expired it seems. Any other way to install ack?

Comment: You'd probably want to add `*.imageset` (both in `find` and `xargs basename`) for asset catalog entries plus `--nojson` to ignore the `Contents.json` asset catalog files. Though obviously a more specific filter would be needed I you have references to your assets in any custom JSON files.

Answer (score 30):

Please have a try [LSUnusedResources](https://github.com/tinymind/LSUnusedResources).

It is heavily influenced by jeffhodnett‘s [Unused](http://jeffhodnett.github.io/Unused/), but honestly Unused is very slow, and the results are not entirely correct. So I made some performance optimization, the search speed is more faster than Unused.

Comment: Wow that is a great tool! Much nicer than trying to run those scripts. You can visually see all of the images not used, and delete the ones you wish. One gotcha I found though is it does not pick up images referenced in the plist

Comment: Definitely awesome and save my day! Best solution in thread. You rock.

Comment: Best one in thread. I wish this was higher up and I could up-vote more than once!

Comment: Do you know if there is something similar to this but for dead code detection? For instance, for methods no longer called (at least no longer *statically called*).

Answer (score 24):

I tried Roman's solution, and I added a few tweaks to handle retina images. It works well, but remember that image names can be generated programmatically in code, and this script would incorrectly list these images as unreferenced. For example, you might have

`NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d.png", 1];`

This script will incorrectly think `image_1.png` is unreferenced.

Here's the modified script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROJ=`find . -name '*.xib' -o -name '*.[mh]' -o -name '*.storyboard' -o -name '*.mm'`

for png in `find . -name '*.png'`
do
   name=`basename -s .png $png`
   name=`basename -s @2x $name`
   if ! grep -qhs "$name" "$PROJ"; then
        echo "$png"
   fi
done
```

Comment: what does the _@2x_ do in the suffix switch for basename?

Comment: The first call to basename will delete the .png suffix and the second call deletes the @2x suffix. The suffixes are deleted from the filenames that find returns. It then looks for the basenames in $PROJ, which contains all the project filenames.

Comment: ah ok, so you actually have images named `something@2x.png` in your system? I thought perhaps `@2x` was some sort of weird regexp or directive that `basename` understood

Comment: Yes, imagename@2x.png images are double size for the retina display.

Comment: I modified the first line such as : PROJ=`find . -name '*.xib' -o -name '*.[mh]' -o -name '*.storyboard' -o -name '*.mm'` because sometimes, you need the mm extension instead of .m

Comment: You should also add `-o -name '*Info.plist'` :)

Comment: This doesn't return any results regardless of how many extra images I drop in the folder. Is there something that needs to be done other than `sh findImages.sh`?

Comment: FYI, folders with spaces in the name cause issues with the script.

Comment: If you encounter error: No such file or directory, it is probably due to the spaces in the file path. The quotes needs to be added in grep line, so it goes: if ! grep -qhs "$name" "$PROJ";

Comment: To further deal with spaces in file/directory names, replace the for statement with the following:

    find . -iname '*.png' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' png

Comment: This script lists all my files

Comment: i dunno why its not working for me its giving me all the png images

Comment: The script also fails, understandably, to spot images referenced in source code such as

    resourceName = self.isSelected
                             ? @"ODSharedIcon_AvatarFrame_Mine_Selected" 
                              : @"ODSharedIcon_AvatarFrame_Mine_Unselected";

So, watch out before you start removing images!

Comment: Script does not work for storyboard files as the images referenced in storyboard do not have .png extension in Interface Builder

Answer (score 13):

May be you can try [slender](http://dragonforged.com/slender/), does a decent job.

**update:** With emcmanus idea, I went ahead and create a small util with no ack just to avoid additional setup in a machine.

https://github.com/arun80/xcodeutils

Comment: Slender is paid app. several false positives and not good for commercial products. script provided by emcmanus is really great.

Answer (score 6):

Only this script is working for me which is even handling the space in the filenames:

#### Edit

Updated to support `swift` files and `cocoapod`. By default it's excluding the Pods dir and check only the project files. To run to check the Pods folder as well, run with `--pod` attrbiute :

`/.finunusedimages.sh --pod`

Here is the actual script:

```
#!/bin/sh

#varables
baseCmd="find ." 
attrs="-name '*.xib' -o -name '*.[mh]' -o -name '*.storyboard' -o -name '*.mm' -o -name '*.swift'"
excudePodFiles="-not \( -path  */Pods/* -prune \)"
imgPathes="find . -iname '*.png' -print0"


#finalize commands
if [ "$1" != "--pod" ]; then
    echo "Pod files excluded"
    attrs="$excudePodFiles $attrs"
    imgPathes="find . $excudePodFiles -iname '*.png' -print0"
fi

#select project files to check
projFiles=`eval "$baseCmd $attrs"`
echo "Looking for in files: $projFiles"

#check images
eval "$imgPathes" | while read -d $'\0' png
do
   name=`basename -s .png "$png"`
   name=`basename -s @2x $name`
   name=`basename -s @3x $name`

   if grep -qhs "$name" $projFiles; then
        echo "(used - $png)"
   else
        echo "!!!UNUSED - $png"
   fi
done
```

Comment: This script have marked too many *used* resources as *unused*. Improvements needed.

Comment: Also doesn't like big, deep project hierarchies:
    ./findunused.sh: line 28: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long

Answer (score 3):

I made a very slight modification to the excellent answer provided by @EdMcManus to handle projects utilizing asset catalogs.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `find . -name "*.imageset"`; do
    file=`basename -s .imageset "$i"`
    result=`ack -i "$file" --ignore-dir="*.xcassets"`
    if [ -z "$result" ]; then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

I don't really write bash scripts, so if there are improvements to be made here (likely) let me know in the comments and I'll update it.

Comment: I have an issue with spaces in files name. I've found out that is useful to set ` IFS=$'\n' `, just before the code (this one sets the internal field separator to new line) - won't work if again files have new lines in name.

Answer (score 3):

Using the other answers, this one is a good example of how to ignore images on two directories and do not search occurrences of the images on the pbxproj or xcassets files (Be careful with the app icon and splash screens). Change the * in the --ignore-dir=*.xcassets to match your directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `find . -not \( -path ./Frameworks -prune \) -not \( -path ./Carthage -prune \) -not \( -path ./Pods -prune \) -name "*.png" -o -name "*.jpg"`; do 
    file=`basename -s .jpg "$i" | xargs basename -s .png | xargs basename -s @2x | xargs basename -s @3x`
    result=`ack -i --ignore-file=ext:pbxproj --ignore-dir=*.xcassets "$file"`
    if [ -z "$result" ]; then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a shell script that `grep` your source code and compare the founded images with your project folder.

Here the man(s) for [`GREP`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) and [`LS`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls)

Easily you can loop all of your source file, save images in array or something equals and use

`cat file.m | grep [-V] myImage.png`

With this trick, you can search all images in your project source code!!

hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a lua script, I'm not sure I can share it because I did it at work, but it works well.  Basically it does this:

**Step one- static image references** (the easy bit, covered by the other answers)

- recursively looks through image dirs and pulls out image names
- strips the image names of .png and @2x (not required/used in imageNamed:)
- textually searches for each image name in the source files (must be inside string literal)

**Step two- dynamic image references** (the fun bit)

- pulls out a list of all string literals in source containing format specifiers (eg, %@)
- replaces format specifiers in these strings with regular expressions (eg, "foo%dbar" becomes "foo[0-9]*bar"
- textually searches through the image names using these regex strings

Then deletes whatever it didn't find in either search.

The edge case is that image names that come from a server aren't handled. To handle this we include the server code in this search.

Comment: Neat. Out of curiosity is there some utility for transforming format specifiers to wildcard regexes? Just thinking there's a lot of complexity you'd have to handle to accurately accomodate all specifiers and platforms. [(Format specifier docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [FauxPas App for Xcode](http://fauxpasapp.com/). It is really good in findings the missing images and a lot of other issues/ violations related to Xcode project.

Comment: Looks like this hasn't been updated since Xcode 9. Can confirm that it does not work with Xcode 11.

Answer (score 2):

I used this framework:-

http://jeffhodnett.github.io/Unused/

Works damn well! Only 2 places I saw issues are when image names are from server and when the image asset name is different from the name of the image inside the asset folder...

Comment: This doesn't look for assets, only for image files that aren't directly referenced. If you're using Assets like you should, this tool will unfortunately not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a python script to identify the unused images: ['unused_assets.py' @ gist](https://gist.github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/05f6142267fc402f10b50360dfc7aaa6). It can be used like this:

```
python3 unused_assets.py '/Users/DevK/MyProject' '/Users/DevK/MyProject/MyProject/Assets/Assets.xcassets'
```

Here are few rules to use the script:

- It is important to pass project folder path as first argument, assets
  folder path as second argument
- It is assumed that all the images are maintained within Assets.xcassets folder and are used either within swift files or within storyboards

Limitations in first version:

- Doesn't work for objective c files

I will try to improve it over the time, based on feedback, however the first version should be good for most.

Please find below the code. *The code should be self explanatory as I have added appropriate comments to each important step*.

```
# Usage e.g.: python3 unused_assets.py '/Users/DevK/MyProject' '/Users/DevK/MyProject/MyProject/Assets/Assets.xcassets'
# It is important to pass project folder path as first argument, assets folder path as second argument
# It is assumed that all the images are maintained within Assets.xcassets folder and are used either within swift files or within storyboards

"""
@author = "Devarshi Kulshreshtha"
@copyright = "Copyright 2020, Devarshi Kulshreshtha"
@license = "GPL"
@version = "1.0.1"
@contact = "kulshreshtha.devarshi@gmail.com"
"""

import sys
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import mmap
import os
import time

# obtain start time
start = time.time()

arguments = sys.argv

# pass project folder path as argument 1
projectFolderPath = arguments[1].replace("\\", "") # replacing backslash with space
# pass assets folder path as argument 2
assetsPath = arguments[2].replace("\\", "") # replacing backslash with space

print(f"assetsPath: {assetsPath}")
print(f"projectFolderPath: {projectFolderPath}")

# obtain all assets / images 
# obtain paths for all assets

assetsSearchablePath = assetsPath + '/**/*.imageset'  #alternate way to append: fr"{assetsPath}/**/*.imageset"
print(f"assetsSearchablePath: {assetsSearchablePath}")

imagesNameCountDict = {} # empty dict to store image name as key and occurrence count
for imagesetPath in glob.glob(assetsSearchablePath, recursive=True):
    # storing the image name as encoded so that we save some time later during string search in file 
    encodedImageName = str.encode(Path(imagesetPath).stem)
    # initializing occurrence count as 0
    imagesNameCountDict[encodedImageName] = 0

print("Names of all assets obtained")

# search images in swift files
# obtain paths for all swift files

swiftFilesSearchablePath = projectFolderPath + '/**/*.swift' #alternate way to append: fr"{projectFolderPath}/**/*.swift"
print(f"swiftFilesSearchablePath: {swiftFilesSearchablePath}")

for swiftFilePath in glob.glob(swiftFilesSearchablePath, recursive=True):
    with open(swiftFilePath, 'rb', 0) as file, \
        mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
        # search all the assests within the swift file
        for encodedImageName in imagesNameCountDict:
            # file search
            if s.find(encodedImageName) != -1:
                # updating occurrence count, if found 
                imagesNameCountDict[encodedImageName] += 1

print("Images searched in all swift files!")

# search images in storyboards
# obtain path for all storyboards

storyboardsSearchablePath = projectFolderPath + '/**/*.storyboard' #alternate way to append: fr"{projectFolderPath}/**/*.storyboard"
print(f"storyboardsSearchablePath: {storyboardsSearchablePath}")
for storyboardPath in glob.glob(storyboardsSearchablePath, recursive=True):
    with open(storyboardPath, 'rb', 0) as file, \
        mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
        # search all the assests within the storyboard file
        for encodedImageName in imagesNameCountDict:
            # file search
            if s.find(encodedImageName) != -1:
                # updating occurrence count, if found
                imagesNameCountDict[encodedImageName] += 1

print("Images searched in all storyboard files!")
print("Here is the list of unused assets:")

# printing all image names, for which occurrence count is 0
print('\n'.join({encodedImageName.decode("utf-8", "strict") for encodedImageName, occurrenceCount in imagesNameCountDict.items() if occurrenceCount == 0}))

print(f"Done in {time.time() - start} seconds!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://jeffhodnett.github.io/Unused/ to find the unused images.

Comment: It seems to me that neither this app handles well the space in the folder names. And it quite slow for one of my larger project.