# Xcode Search and Destroy

Tags: ios, xcode, removeall

I'm trying to clean up my project in `iOS XCode`. I know you can do this in other tools but I'm unsure with `Xcode`. I have googled but I'm getting the impression this can't be done. Is there a way to search your project for unused items i.e. images and then remove them if not required?

Comment: i dont think u can do this through any tool .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard about Slender :
is one of tools that tells you which asset files aren't being used. Along the way, you can also see which assets are missing their @1x counterparts, or if your @2x images have incorrect pixel

[Slender Link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slender/id493656257?mt=12)

Hope it helps.

There is also one question that helps you too [How to find unused images in an XCode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113243/how-to-find-unused-images-in-an-xcode-project)

Comment: Perfect. Using the combination of the two should do nicely! Thanks again!!