# How to remove unused images from an Xcode project

Tags: ios, shell

I'm following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113243/how-to-find-unused-images-in-an-xcode-project) to find the unused images from an xcode project but they are not working well for me. I tried Rob's answer and Roman's answer but they give me all the png images.
I tried to use the [tool](http://maniacdev.com/2013/01/tool-for-finding-unused-images-within-an-xcode-project-to-help-reduce-app-bundle-size) it also giving me all png images

**EDIT**

The way Im using script
1)i copy script and paste it in the terminal and press Enter.

2) save the script in txt file and in terminal i type `sh myscript.txt`

[image]

Comment: it works don't blame to authors

Comment: @iDev i hope they do. BUt they are not working for me

Comment: I dunno why people mark question duplicate without reading the whole question look like they just copy paste the title on google and mark duplicate

Comment: so for change you sentence  as "they are not working for me "

Answer (score 0):

I have created a python script to identify the unused images in a **swift** project: ['unused_assets.py' @ gist](https://gist.github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/05f6142267fc402f10b50360dfc7aaa6), which can be easily tweaked for an objective-c project as yours.

The script can be used like this:

```
python3 unused_assets.py '/Users/DevK/MyProject' '/Users/DevK/MyProject/MyProject/Assets/Assets.xcassets'
```

Here are few rules to use the script:

- It is important to pass project folder path as first argument, assets folder path as second argument
- It is assumed that all the images are maintained within Assets.xcassets folder and are used either within swift/ objective-c files or within storyboards

Limitations in first version:

- Doesn't work for objective c files, but can be tweaked to achieve expected behavior as specified in comment in below code

I will try to improve it over the time, based on feedback, however the first version should be good for most.

Here is the code. *I tried to make the code self explanatory by adding appropriate comments to each important step, let me know if you still need more details*.

```
# Usage e.g.: python3 unused_assets.py '/Users/DevK/MyProject' '/Users/DevK/MyProject/MyProject/Assets/Assets.xcassets'
# It is important to pass project folder path as first argument, assets folder path as second argument
# It is assumed that all the images are maintained within Assets.xcassets folder and are used either within swift files or within storyboards

"""
@author = "Devarshi Kulshreshtha"
@copyright = "Copyright 2020, Devarshi Kulshreshtha"
@license = "GPL"
@version = "1.0.1"
@contact = "kulshreshtha.devarshi@gmail.com"
"""

import sys
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import mmap
import os
import time

# obtain start time
start = time.time()

arguments = sys.argv

# pass project folder path as argument 1
projectFolderPath = arguments[1].replace("\\", "") # replacing backslash with space
# pass assets folder path as argument 2
assetsPath = arguments[2].replace("\\", "") # replacing backslash with space

print(f"assetsPath: {assetsPath}")
print(f"projectFolderPath: {projectFolderPath}")

# obtain all assets / images 
# obtain paths for all assets

assetsSearchablePath = assetsPath + '/**/*.imageset'  #alternate way to append: fr"{assetsPath}/**/*.imageset"
print(f"assetsSearchablePath: {assetsSearchablePath}")

imagesNameCountDict = {} # empty dict to store image name as key and occurrence count
for imagesetPath in glob.glob(assetsSearchablePath, recursive=True):
    # storing the image name as encoded so that we save some time later during string search in file 
    encodedImageName = str.encode(Path(imagesetPath).stem)
    # initializing occurrence count as 0
    imagesNameCountDict[encodedImageName] = 0

print("Names of all assets obtained")

# search images in swift files
# obtain paths for all swift files

# For objective-c project, change '/**/*.swift' to '/**/*.m' 
swiftFilesSearchablePath = projectFolderPath + '/**/*.swift' #alternate way to append: fr"{projectFolderPath}/**/*.swift"
print(f"swiftFilesSearchablePath: {swiftFilesSearchablePath}")

for swiftFilePath in glob.glob(swiftFilesSearchablePath, recursive=True):
    with open(swiftFilePath, 'rb', 0) as file, \
        mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
        # search all the assests within the swift file
        for encodedImageName in imagesNameCountDict:
            # file search
            if s.find(encodedImageName) != -1:
                # updating occurrence count, if found 
                imagesNameCountDict[encodedImageName] += 1

print("Images searched in all swift files!")

# search images in storyboards
# obtain path for all storyboards

storyboardsSearchablePath = projectFolderPath + '/**/*.storyboard' #alternate way to append: fr"{projectFolderPath}/**/*.storyboard"
print(f"storyboardsSearchablePath: {storyboardsSearchablePath}")
for storyboardPath in glob.glob(storyboardsSearchablePath, recursive=True):
    with open(storyboardPath, 'rb', 0) as file, \
        mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
        # search all the assests within the storyboard file
        for encodedImageName in imagesNameCountDict:
            # file search
            if s.find(encodedImageName) != -1:
                # updating occurrence count, if found
                imagesNameCountDict[encodedImageName] += 1

print("Images searched in all storyboard files!")
print("Here is the list of unused assets:")

# printing all image names, for which occurrence count is 0
print('\n'.join({encodedImageName.decode("utf-8", "strict") for encodedImageName, occurrenceCount in imagesNameCountDict.items() if occurrenceCount == 0}))

print(f"Done in {time.time() - start} seconds!")
```