# Remove unused resources from XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on iOs application and in this application i have big changes in app design every day so code of my application is going to touch about 200 Mb. But in this code i have big numbers of  unused images are available. So i want to remove those images from my XCode project so i can reduce my project code size.

I had used some scripts thats already given on stackoverflow.com but i found that script removing used images also so thats not reliable. 
I also had used app named "Slender". Its really good but its trial version so i cant use it more.

So please any one suggest me effective way (any application) for remove unused images from xCode project.

Answer (score 1):

Unused will help you find unused resources in xCode project https://github.com/jeffhodnett/Unused

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question over here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62078601/217586](https://gist.github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/05f6142267fc402f10b50360dfc7aaa6)

Adding the same details, here:

I have created a python script to identify the unused images: ['unused_assets.py' @ gist](https://gist.github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/05f6142267fc402f10b50360dfc7aaa6). It can be used like this:

```
python3 unused_assets.py '/Users/DevK/MyProject' '/Users/DevK/MyProject/MyProject/Assets/Assets.xcassets'
```

Here are few rules to use the script:

- It is important to pass project folder path as first argument, assets
  folder path as second argument
- It is assumed that all the images are maintained within Assets.xcassets folder and are used either within swift files or within storyboards

Limitations in first version:

- Doesn't work for objective c files

I will try to improve it over the time, based on feedback, however the first version should be good for most.

Please find below the code. *The code should be self explanatory as I have added appropriate comments to each important step*.

```
# Usage e.g.: python3 unused_assets.py '/Users/DevK/MyProject' '/Users/DevK/MyProject/MyProject/Assets/Assets.xcassets'
# It is important to pass project folder path as first argument, assets folder path as second argument
# It is assumed that all the images are maintained within Assets.xcassets folder and are used either within swift files or within storyboards

"""
@author = "Devarshi Kulshreshtha"
@copyright = "Copyright 2020, Devarshi Kulshreshtha"
@license = "GPL"
@version = "1.0.1"
@contact = "kulshreshtha.devarshi@gmail.com"
"""

import sys
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import mmap
import os
import time

# obtain start time
start = time.time()

arguments = sys.argv

# pass project folder path as argument 1
projectFolderPath = arguments[1].replace("\\", "") # replacing backslash with space
# pass assets folder path as argument 2
assetsPath = arguments[2].replace("\\", "") # replacing backslash with space

print(f"assetsPath: {assetsPath}")
print(f"projectFolderPath: {projectFolderPath}")

# obtain all assets / images 
# obtain paths for all assets

assetsSearchablePath = assetsPath + '/**/*.imageset'  #alternate way to append: fr"{assetsPath}/**/*.imageset"
print(f"assetsSearchablePath: {assetsSearchablePath}")

imagesNameCountDict = {} # empty dict to store image name as key and occurrence count
for imagesetPath in glob.glob(assetsSearchablePath, recursive=True):
    # storing the image name as encoded so that we save some time later during string search in file 
    encodedImageName = str.encode(Path(imagesetPath).stem)
    # initializing occurrence count as 0
    imagesNameCountDict[encodedImageName] = 0

print("Names of all assets obtained")

# search images in swift files
# obtain paths for all swift files

swiftFilesSearchablePath = projectFolderPath + '/**/*.swift' #alternate way to append: fr"{projectFolderPath}/**/*.swift"
print(f"swiftFilesSearchablePath: {swiftFilesSearchablePath}")

for swiftFilePath in glob.glob(swiftFilesSearchablePath, recursive=True):
    with open(swiftFilePath, 'rb', 0) as file, \
        mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
        # search all the assests within the swift file
        for encodedImageName in imagesNameCountDict:
            # file search
            if s.find(encodedImageName) != -1:
                # updating occurrence count, if found 
                imagesNameCountDict[encodedImageName] += 1

print("Images searched in all swift files!")

# search images in storyboards
# obtain path for all storyboards

storyboardsSearchablePath = projectFolderPath + '/**/*.storyboard' #alternate way to append: fr"{projectFolderPath}/**/*.storyboard"
print(f"storyboardsSearchablePath: {storyboardsSearchablePath}")
for storyboardPath in glob.glob(storyboardsSearchablePath, recursive=True):
    with open(storyboardPath, 'rb', 0) as file, \
        mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
        # search all the assests within the storyboard file
        for encodedImageName in imagesNameCountDict:
            # file search
            if s.find(encodedImageName) != -1:
                # updating occurrence count, if found
                imagesNameCountDict[encodedImageName] += 1

print("Images searched in all storyboard files!")
print("Here is the list of unused assets:")

# printing all image names, for which occurrence count is 0
print('\n'.join({encodedImageName.decode("utf-8", "strict") for encodedImageName, occurrenceCount in imagesNameCountDict.items() if occurrenceCount == 0}))

print(f"Done in {time.time() - start} seconds!")
```